# BlueStacks 5 error: cannot start BlueStacks

Tags: android, windows, virtualization, bluestacks

I just installed BlueStacks 5 but when I want to open it I get this error:

> cannot start BlueStacks. Please send a problem report

[image]

Additional info:
Virtualization is enabled from my end (in Bios) but "Intel® Processor Identification Utility" says it's not!

[image]

[image]

**What's the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was "**Virtualization-based security or VBS**":

[How to Disable VBS and Speed Up Windows 11](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/disable-vbs-windows-11)